# Add a "Back to login" button to the error.ftl page

Tags: keycloak

I would like the user to be able to return back to the login page if an error occurs.

E.g. The user clicks forgot password, the link expires, they use the link. Currently they get taken to the error.ftl with the `expiredActionTokenNoSessionMessage` displayed. The UX would be better if they can click the "Back to login" button to then use the forgot password flow again.

Is it possible to add a button that will take the user back to the login page? I've tried redirecting to `/login-actions/authenticate` but it displays this error (likely due to there being no client ID or other query parameters?).

[image: We are sorry error]